# how to select users who login more than once every 3 seconds in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Write a shell script (to run on the Bourne shell) that runs an infinite loop to monitor which users on a denial list have logged into the UNIX system more than once.

1. The denial list must be stored in a text file named user.deny which lists which users are not allowed multiple logins, specified by one username per line.
2. In the beginning of the script you need to check that the user.deny file exists under the current directory, and if not, your script displays a message to say so and then exits.
3. Every 3 seconds, the script must display a warning message to report users on the denial list who have logged in multiple times. Display the user’s full name instead of his/her username in the warning message.
4. It’s unnecessary for your script to handle the situation where a user logs in and then logs off immediately (i.e. within a 3 second interval).

Your script for this task must be named `mlog.sh`. The following is a sample output of the script (It is OK if the script leaves behind temporary files when it is finally interrupted). The $ is the shell prompt.

```
$ ./mlog.sh
No user on the user.deny list has multiple logins
No user on the user.deny list has multiple logins
The user John Smith (on the denial list) has logged in more than once!
The user Adam Jones (on the denial list) has logged in more than once!
No user on the user.deny list has multiple logins
No user on the user.deny list has multiple logins
The user David Monks (on the denial list) has logged in more than once!
The user Nick Andrews (on the denial list) has logged in more than once!
```

Remember don't use root account privilege, as students, we don't have root privileges and we can use who, users, w, finger to monitor the users that login the system.

w :

```
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
juanz    pts/1    myvpn-35-37.stud 07:34    1:09m  0.20s  0.20s -bash
haydenj2 pts/0    myvpn-p32-107.st 07:23    0.00s  0.90s  0.90s -bash
fhe2     pts/2    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-e 08:04    6:39   0.14s  0.01s nano menu.sh
chanpw   pts/3    myvpn-33-186.stu 07:51    0.00s  0.14s  0.06s joe cp2.sh
fhe2     pts/4    10-200-250-132-e 08:19   35:56   0.08s  0.08s -bash
zijianc  pts/5    myvpn-33-162.stu 02:36    6:33m  0.05s  0.05s -bash
zijianc  pts/6    myvpn-33-162.stu 02:35    6:32m  0.10s  0.02s nano
```

I don't know how to use the table to display...

Looking forward to your response!

Comment: This question will probably get closed unless you make an attempt at it and edit the question to show what you tried.

Comment: if [ -f user.deny ]; then
while true
do

        finger | awk '{print $1}' | tee text3.txt
        sleep 3;
        finger | awk '{print $1}' | tee user.deny
        diff text3.txt user.deny;
done

else
echo "no user.deny file error!";
fi

Comment: You might also find the [last](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1.html) command is useful here.

Comment: As well as the `who` command.

Answer (score 0):

haha, here is my codes:

if [ -f user.deny ];then
    finger | awk '{w[$2" "$3]+=1}END{for(a in w)if(w[a]>1) print a}' > user.deny

while true;
do
    finger | awk '{w[$2" "$3]+=1}END{for(a in w)if(w[a]>1) print a}' >user.deny | while read line
    do
    #finger | awk '{w[$2" "$3]+=1}END{for(a in w)if(w[a]>1) print a}' > user.deny 
    FN=`wc -l<user.deny`;
    if [ $FN -eq 0 ];then
    echo "No user on the user.deny list has multiple logins";
    else
    echo "$line user on the user.deny list has multiple logins"; 
    #sleep 3
    fi
    done < user.deny
done
else 
    echo "no user.deny,exit";
    exit;
fi